# Is repurposing a window okay

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I'm in the process of writing an application which will allow the user to generate a variety of reports. There is a button which will bring up another window allowing the user to choose a specific date for the report. Now, my boss wants the head label to read what you're selected a date for, i.e. "Payroll Report Date Selection" or "Employee Report Date Selection". In my situation, this window looks exactly the same, aside from this label. My question is, is it feasible to reuse this window and just change the label based upon a passed parameter, or should I have a window for each? The code is going to work the same on all of them. Are there benefits to reusing the same window versus one window for each one?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same window. It would be nonsense to create one window per report if they are all exactly the same except for the label.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), you make it harder to maintain if you use different classes doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying code and window are the same, then you shouldn't have to create a brand new window.  Just dynamically change the content of the label based on the user's selected value.